# Easiest way to add google maps to Fragments in Android?

Tags: android, maps

I am new to Android Development and I would like to know what is the easiest way that i can insert google maps in fragments. All guides I have found online are rather difficult for a beginner-level developer.

All help is appreciated.

Comment: you can create map activity easily in android studio 
go to activity package right click >> new>>google>>google map activity

Answer (score 0):

this guide is pretty simple and easy to work with. Try it out.
https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Google-Maps-Fragment-Guide

Answer (score 0):

Google Maps is integrated in your app using the SupportMapFragment class. So you see, map itself is type of fragment. Now the question really is, how to insert fragments into your activity.

You can do it via XML or progrmatically. For XML insertion, you can insert this code into your XML :

```
        <fragment
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:id="@+id/map_fragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Then in your java file, you would get a refrence of this fragment like this :

`mapFragment             = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.googleMapFragment);`

In case you have your own custom fragment and would like to insert a map fragment into your custom fragment, you will follow the same strategy above but will have the XML and Java code in your respective custom fragment files.